# Trying to execute JavaScript inside if-else

Tags: javascript

```
private void GoogleAnalyticsJavascript()
{
//...
}

private void WriteMetaTags()
        {

                try
                {
                    MetaTagHelper metaControl = new MetaTagHelper();
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.pn_sku", GetSemicolonSeparatedValues(this.CurrentOrder, "ProductCode"), this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_u", GetSemicolonSeparatedValues(this.CurrentOrder, "Quantity"), this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_s", GetSemicolonSeparatedValues(this.CurrentOrder, "Total"), this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_e", "p", this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.si_n", "Purchase", this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.si_x", "7", this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.ti", "Receipt", this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.si_cs", "1", this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_cartid", this.CurrentOrder.Id, this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_i", this.CurrentOrder.OrderNumber, this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_id", this.CurrentOrder.DateModified.Value.ToString("d"), this.Page);
                    metaControl.AddMetaTag("WT.tx_it", this.CurrentOrder.DateModified.Value.ToString("H:mm:ss"), this.Page);

                    GoogleAnalyticsJavascript();

                }


                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
```

The code above works, but what I want `GoogleAnalyticsJavaScript()` only to fire when I go to the page "crazy.aspx". I'm using this but it's not working.

```
string currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
if (currentUrl.ToLower().Contains("crazy.aspx"))
{
    GoogleAnalyticsJavascript();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens on that if condition when you request crazy.aspx?

Comment: I don't see an if else anywhere anyways

Comment: I want GoogleAnalyticsJavaScript() to execute when crazy.aspx page is loaded. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: That's not JavaScript!

Comment: Do you know how to debug? (i.e. set a break point, execute the program, and step through the code)